# The query editor keeps the connection of older login if I disconnect and reconnect with a new login in Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I disconnect using Object Explorer and then I reconnect using another login (with SQL Server Authentication)
the connection of the query editor remains tied with the old login.

Is there a way to sync the connections in a way that if I disconnect under Object explorer and then reconnect using another login, the connection
of query editor also changes to the current login?

Comment: Correct. Each tab in SSMS has its own connection, separate from one another as well as from the Object Explorer. Just close the old tabs and open new ones, or [change the connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/solution/change-the-connection-associated-with-a-query).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes I've figured it out. I created multiple logins mapped to different users in a database. I was testing if permissions worked  properly so I connected to the server in Object Explorer using a  different login  but when executing queries I had all sysadmin privilges and it was because the editor was tied with my windows authentication login which is member of sysadmin.

Comment: As a sysadmin you can run `execute as user='someuser'` to impersonate a user and test permissions.  Then `revert` to undo the impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in order to reopen all SQL scripts with another connection I had to go to `File->Open->File with New Connection`